# c# different file content for debug and release

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I have `.txt` file which I want some parts of its content to be different for debug and release build.

```
{Bunch of text. debug and release...}

#if DEBUG
{My texts onlyfor debug build}
#else
{And texts onlyfor release}
#endif

{Other bunch of texts...}
```

Is such thing possible?

Comment: Text files aren't code and can't have debug directives. Use different files instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate your .txt file when your application starts based on your example using `#if DEBUG` statements.

You could even include your two files as myFile.txt.debug and myFile.txt.release and then copy the right one to myFile.txt when the application starts. These could be included as content files or in your projects resources.

For XML and JSON files you can use https://github.com/microsoft/slow-cheetah to generate file based on your build configuration.